# Chaining multiple Linq Where calls as an OR, not an AND

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have filtering code that I am refactoring that presently has a large number of IF blocks to determine the way to apply a filter.

It currently looks at the various options for filters and builds one big Linq (to EF) statement that does everything.

When you chain multiple Linq `.Where` calls, the resultant operation is an AND. How do you do an OR when chaining multiple `.Where` calls.

For example

```
users = users.Where(l => l.Location == "MyLocation")
users = users.Where(r => r.Role == "Role")
```

The result would be the same as

```
users = users.Where(u => u.Location == "MyLocation" && u.Role == "Role")
```

Where I want

```
users = users.Where(u => u.Location == "MyLocation" || u.Role == "Role")
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for `PredicateBuilder`.

Comment: just showing what slaks pointed out briliantly - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: @SLaks Thanks heaps I didn't know about it and it's a great bit of code. Can you please add an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: See also http://blog.abodit.com/2013/02/creating-and-or-expressions-linq/ which explains why PredicateBuilder might not be the answer you are looking for and offers an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), which can construct expression trees from logical operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
users = users.Where(l => l.Location == "MyLocation")
    .Union(users.Where(r => r.Role == "Role"));
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: This solution should work. However it has a major drawback : it uses `Union` which will certainly result in comparing two sets (depends on the implementation of the Linq to ...). The solution using `PredicateBuilder` should be much more efficient in case of big database.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code to execute OK.
`users = users.Where(u => u.Location == "MyLocation" || u.Role == "Role")`

My test code is follow:

```
 private class User
    {
        public string Location = "MyLocation";
        public string Role = "Role";
        public string Data = "TestData";
    }
private void LinqOr()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        IEnumerable<User> users = new User[] {
                        new User{Location="MyLocation",Role="Role",Data="Data1"},
                        new User{Location="MyLocation",Role="Role",Data="Data2"},
                        new User{Location="MyLocationB",Role="Role3",Data="Data3"},
                        new User{Location="MyLocationB",Role="Role4",Data="Data4"},
                        new User{Location="MyLocationC",Role="Role",Data="Data5"},
                        new User{Location="MyLocationC",Role="Role",Data="Data6"},
                        new User{Location="MyLocationD",Role="Role7",Data="Data7"},
        };

        //users = users.Where(l => l.Location == "MyLocation");
        //users = users.Where(R => R.Role == "Role");
        //users = users.Where(u => u.Location == "MyLocation" && u.Role == "Role");
        users = users.Where(u => u.Location == "MyLocation" || u.Role == "Role");
        string result = "";
        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            result += user.Location + " " + user.Role + " " + user.Data + "\r\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }


    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        LinqOr();
    }
```

Result as shown in the figure.

[image]